# jQuery disable button if either input is empty

Tags: jquery

A button is disabled by default. There are two text inputs. If either are empty, the form should remain disabled. If both fields have value, the button should be enabled.

Trying this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#custNameNext').prop('disabled',true);
    $('#customer').keyup(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\w\s]+/g, ''));
        $('#custNameNext').prop('disabled', ((this.value == '') || ($('#customerCost').val() == '')) ? true : false);
    });
});
```

... but b/c I'm in a keyup, the button does not enable unless I have values in both fields, AND THEN RETURN to the first field with the keyup and enter additional text.

Having trouble thinking this thru!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#custNameNext').prop('disabled', true);

  function validateNextButton() {
    var buttonDisabled = $('#customer').val().trim() === '' || $('#customerCost').val().trim() === '';
    $('#custNameNext').prop('disabled', buttonDisabled);
  }

  $('#customer').on('keyup', validateNextButton);
  $('#customerCost').on('keyup', validateNextButton);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="customer" name="first-input" type="text">
  <input id="customerCost" name="second-input" type="text">
  <input id="custNameNext" type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="disabled">
</form>
```

I have inserted the ids you already had in your snippet. As a suggestion, it would be better to omit long lines of code and split them into more coherent ones.

The test statement held into `buttonDisabled` can be changed, would you require any other validation for the submit button to be enabled (such as regex).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Worked great for me as it incorporated the keyup function I needed. Having both fields use the same validation function is a brilliant way to make sure neither are empty, no matter which one is filled in first! I added my regex to validateNextButton and works like a charm!

Comment: Very glad to help, @webguy.

Answer (score 2):

You can add both inputs to the event handler, and by using the `input` event you'll capture pasting and a few other scenarios as well.

Then just filter on the values to check if any of them are empty

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#custNameNext').prop('disabled', true);

    $('#customer, #customerCost').on('input', function() {
          var val = $('#customer, #customerCost').filter(function() {
                return this.value.trim().length !== 0;
        }).length === 0;

        $('#custNameNext').prop('disabled', val);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/v6e34f4n/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I could not easily figure out how to integrate the keyup I needed to limit what could go in the customer filed, but I learned something from your answer and I appreciate that!